# Flutter Dio.post login API response code is 200 but not validating user credentials on mobile working fine in postman and web

Tags: flutter

I'm interacting with  a login Api in a flutter app using the DIO package the API is working fine in postman and for web,
In Flutter app its response code is 200 but does not validate the user credentials. and return failed.

Comment: please share the code for better understanding

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please kindly share your log and code so I can review them to know the source of the issue.
But there are instances where the status code can be 200 but the user might not be authenticated, implying that the request was sent to the server successfully.
I will suggest you error = true or false so that you can check the status code and error for any response.
Example:

```
if(response.status == 200 && !response.body.error){
// Then the API will return the data here
}
```